# Balancing Per-Class Accuracy of Multiclass Classifier

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn, precision-recall, multi-class

Suppose I have a multi-class classifier like Naive Bayes, k-Nearest Neighbors, Decision Trees, Random Forest, etc.

The classifier maps a feature vector to (let's say) 3 classes: A, B, or C. My problem is that the accuracy I get from this classifier is drastically different per-class, for example:

```
A: 93%
B: 68%
C: 27%
```

I would like to achieve equal or similar **per-class** accuracy, even if it results in lower average accuracy, like:

```
A: 53%
B: 51%
C: 56%
```

At the very least, I would like to boost the accuracy on classes that have below-random accuracy.

Most people working on multi-class problems seem to report average accuracy, not minimum per-class accuracy or sensitivity. [This paper](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/keel/articulo/5428802.pdf) uses neural nets to address this problem.

**My question:** Are there systematic ways of adjusting either (1) the input to the classifier, (2) the parameters of the classifier, or (3) the output of a **multi-class** classifier in order to balance its per-class accuracy?

*Note: I'm working with Python's scikit-learn module.*

Comment: Just as a warning: not all classifiers are created equal. Techniques that work for one might not work for another.

Comment: What classifier are you using? Does it output probabilities or just classes?

Comment: And what fraction of your training data belongs to each class?

Comment: @BenKuhn I'm getting the same imbalance on each of the classifier I specified above: Naive Bayes, k-Nearest Neighbors, Decision Trees, Random Forest. There is an equal number of training samples for each class (this is achieved by subsampling).